# My Javascript Code isn't Working

Tags: javascript

Why does this work:

```
upButton.addEventListener('click', function(){player.up()}, false);
//downButton.addEventListener('click', function(){player.down()}, false);
```

but this doesn't work:

```
upButton.addEventListener('click', function(){player.up()}, false);
downButton.addEventListener('click', function(){player.down()}, false);
```

These are the buttons:

```
var upButton = document.getElementById('up');
var downButton = document.getElementById('down');
```

Right now the program just prints out "Hello World" to a canvas.  When I add the event listener to the downButton, it won't print anything.  The canvas appears but I don't see the "Hello World" message.

I am very confused.  Thanks for the help.

Here is a link to the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/PPuCR/9/embedded/result/

Comment: Pretty hard to say without seeing what `player.up()` and `player.down()` do. Are there error messages in the JavaScript console?

Comment: is there any error? check the console. If possible make a Jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please also check/show the html (does the down button have the correct id? Is it the only element with the id "down"?)

Comment: post the error message that appears in console.

Comment: Right now the program only prints "hello world" the player.up() and player.down() don't do anything yet since I have not yet written the code for it.  They don't exist yet.

Comment: Please show the rest of your code (click "edit" and amend your question). What you've shown so far doesn't print anything anywhere...

Comment: Is it possible to post the complete .js and .html code? It helps us help you ;-).

Comment: [10:18:12.074] Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead

Comment: TypeError: downButton is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your fiddle, you have capitalized ID's for `right` and `down`.  There are case sensitive.  I filled in the blanks with a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/guydog28/duYBu/

Answer (score 0):

Your down button **id** is `Down` not `down` so use the below line

```
var downButton = document.getElementById('Down');
```

Note : id of an element is **case-sensitive**

Answer (score 0):

Please consider respecting naming conventions "down" "Down".
Anyway, I think I fix it.

```
var upButton = document.getElementById('up');
var downButton = document.getElementById('down');
```

Here is the link  : http://jsfiddle.net/PPuCR/15/embedded/result/

Have a nice day.

Comment: This fiddle will still break when the OP implements "right" arrow, since that still has mismatched case-sensitivity.